# Smooth animated Collapsing Toolbar with Android Design Support Library

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Are there anyway to make Android Design Support Library's Collapsing animation smoother while scrolling? When I release scrolling, it stops suddenly. But what I want is: collapsing animation will continue smoothly even if you stop scrolling.
[Android-ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) and [Scrollable](https://github.com/noties/Scrollable) are the libraries that are collapsing smoothly.

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923889/flinging-with-recyclerview-appbarlayout) has been asked, which links to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177729). It seems therefore that this is a bug which will be solved when version 23 of the library is released.

Comment: Try and understand the code of this [Smooth App Bar](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout) Library.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the new layout_scrollFlag snap for smooth scroll within the AppBarLayout states. But what I have experienced is that, when the RecyclerView reaches top, scrolling stops. i.e CollapsingToolbarLayout won't get expanded without another scroll. For the RecyclerView to scroll smoothly up and expand the CollapsingToolbarLayout I have used a ScrollListener on recyclerview.

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        int scrollDy = 0;
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            scrollDy += dy;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(scrollDy==0&&(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE))
            {
                AppBarLayout appBarLayout = ((AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.app_bar));

                appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

I used "scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" as layout_scrollFlags.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="80dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

Comment: Good solution but there is a speed difference between the scroll and expand :)

Answer (score 7):

This one is fairly new, but the AppBarLayout has been recently updated to handle exactly what you're looking for with a new layout_scrollFlag called [`snap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP).

Usage:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
```

I'll try to look for my source and update my answer when I do.

Edit: Of course, it's from the [android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/android-support-library-231.html).

Comment: thanx help to auto push up and down when swipe half

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing it through `AppBarLayout`. by overriding `onNestedFling` and `onNestedPreScroll`.

> The trick is to reconsume fling event if ScrollingView's top child is close to the beginning of data in Adapter.

Source  [Flinging with RecyclerView + AppBarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30923889/6017001])

```
public final class FlingBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {
private static final int TOP_CHILD_FLING_THRESHOLD = 3;
private boolean isPositive;

public FlingBehavior() {
}

public FlingBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
@Override
public boolean onNestedFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
    if (velocityY > 0 && !isPositive || velocityY < 0 && isPositive) {
        velocityY = velocityY * -1;
    }
    if (target instanceof RecyclerView && velocityY < 0) {
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) target;
        final View firstChild = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
        final int childAdapterPosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(firstChild);
        consumed = childAdapterPosition > TOP_CHILD_FLING_THRESHOLD;
    }
    return super.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
}

@Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
    super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed);
    isPositive = dy > 0;
  }
}
```

Then set the layout behavior as `FlingBehavior` class

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
app:layout_behavior="package.FlingBehavior"
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dip"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

add code

```
 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

in the view inside the AppBarLayout. This is my demo code collapsing the Toolbar with Android Design Support Library.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <bubee.inews.Items.ItemMenu
                android:id="@+id/itemMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect, finally have a smooth scroll.

Comment: This is not collapsing Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code:

```
   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this problem too and have come up with may not very optimized solution but you can improve it.Once I improve it I will definitely edit answer till the have a look at this.

```
public abstract class AppBarStateChangeListener implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
private static final String TAG = "app_AppBarStateChange";
public enum State {
    EXPANDED,
    COLLAPSED,
    IDLE
}

private State mCurrentState = State.IDLE;
private int mInitialPosition = 0;
private boolean mWasExpanded;
private boolean isAnimating;
@Override
public final void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        if (mCurrentState != State.EXPANDED) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.EXPANDED);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.EXPANDED;
        mInitialPosition = 0;
        mWasExpanded = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "onOffsetChanged 1");
        isAnimating = false;
        appBarLayout.setEnabled(true);
    } else if (Math.abs(i) >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
        if (mCurrentState != State.COLLAPSED) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.COLLAPSED);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.COLLAPSED;
        mInitialPosition = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
        mWasExpanded = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "onOffsetChanged 2");
        isAnimating = false;
        appBarLayout.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onOffsetChanged 3");
        int diff = Math.abs(Math.abs(i) - mInitialPosition);
        if(diff >= appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()/3 && !isAnimating) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onOffsetChanged 4");
            isAnimating = true;
            appBarLayout.setEnabled(false);
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(!mWasExpanded,true);
        }
        if (mCurrentState != State.IDLE) {
            onStateChanged(appBarLayout, State.IDLE);
        }
        mCurrentState = State.IDLE;
    }
}

public abstract void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state);

public State getCurrentState() {
    return mCurrentState;
}
```

}

Create this class and call following code

```
private AppBarStateChangeListener mAppBarStateChangeListener = new AppBarStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ToBeDeletedActivity.onStateChanged :: " + state);
        if(state == State.EXPANDED || state == State.IDLE) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello World");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mAppBarLayout.setElevation(0);
            }
        }
    }


};

mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(mAppBarStateChangeListener);
```

Note that do not set annonymous class OffsetChangedListener as this is kept as weak reference and will be collected by GC.I found my self in hard way.

Kindly explore this code and improve it(anyone) and re-share it .Thanks