# CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't recognize scroll fling

Tags: java, android, xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have created a simple **CollapsingToolbarLayout** and it works like a charm. My problem is, that if I try to use a fling scroll on the **nestedscrollview**, it just stops when I release my finger. Normal scrolling works like it should.

My activities code is ***unchanged => auto*** generated empty activity. (I just clicked on create new empty activity in android studio and edited the XML yet).

I read here, that scroll gestures on the imageview itself are buggy, but not, that the scrolling itself is buggy: [see here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176673).

I tried activating ***"smooth scrolling"*** through java code. It seems like if I scroll far enough that the imageview isn't visible anymore, fling gestures then are recognized.

**TLDR:** Why does the fling gesture not work as long as the imageview is visible ?
My XML Code looks like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="420dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/headerbg"
                android:maxHeight="192dp"

                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size_normal"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size_normal"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/profile_content_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:minHeight="192dp"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/LoremIpsum"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Interesting, I logged the touch events on the nested scroll view during an affected fling. It gets `ACTION_DOWN y=98 -> ACTION_MOVE y=-40 -> ACTION_MOVE y=-33 -> ACTION_UP y=97`. It looks like the last touch event is misreporting itself as being next to the first one.

Comment: Which version of the design support library are you using?

Comment: are you overriding any touch events? try setting `nestedScrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` to your nested scroll view

Comment: [Android Support Library 26.0.0-beta2 fixes this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45234111/1954497)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue with **CollapsingToolbarLayout** with **ImageView** inside and **NestedScrollView**. The fling scroll stops when finger is released.

However, I've noticed something strange. If you start scrolling with your finger from a view with OnClickListener (e.g. Button), the fling scrolling works perfectly.

Thus I fixed it with a weird solution. Set OnClickListener (that does nothing) on the direct child of **NestedScrollView**. Then it works perfectly!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Page Content -->

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Give the direct child (LinearLayout) an id and set OnClickListener in Activity

```
ViewGroup mContentContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_container);    
mContentContainer.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int viewId = view.getId();
}
```

**Notes:**

Tested using Support Design Library 25.0.1

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout with scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```

Comment: AOSP should be patched with this great solution :D

Comment: Should get more vote lol.
Btw this made the CollapsingToolbarLayout very sensitive to scroll, but better than the current broken behavior.

Comment: this was too good to be true so i tried it and its not working for me

Comment: this is the craziest solution I have tried so far in SO.

Comment: :D great observation @jinang !!

Comment: It works like a charm, also if you set in the xml clickable=true, you don't need to set the click listener.

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 10):

I know this question was asked over a year ago but this issue still doesn't seem to be resolved in the Support/Design libraries. You can [star this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183738) issue so it moves farther up in the priority queue.

That said, I tried most of the posted solutions for this, including the one by patrick-iv with no success. The only way I was able to get to work was to mimic the fling and call it programmatically if a certain set of conditions were detected in `onPreNestedScroll()`. In the few hours of my debugging I noticed that the `onNestedFling()` was never called on an upward (scroll down) fling and seemed to be consumed prematurely. I can't say with 100% certainty this will work for 100% of implementations but it works well enough for my uses so I ended up settling for this, even though it's pretty hacky and definitely not what I wanted to do.

```
public class NestedScrollViewBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

    // Lower value means fling action is more easily triggered
    static final int MIN_DY_DELTA = 4;
    // Lower values mean less velocity, higher means higher velocity
    static final int FLING_FACTOR = 20;

    int mTotalDy;
    int mPreviousDy;
    WeakReference<AppBarLayout> mPreScrollChildRef;

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child,
                                  View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed);
        // Reset the total fling delta distance if the user starts scrolling back up
        if(dy < 0) {
            mTotalDy = 0;
        }
        // Only track move distance if the movement is positive (since the bug is only present
        // in upward flings), equal to the consumed value and the move distance is greater
        // than the minimum difference value
        if(dy > 0 && consumed[1] == dy && MIN_DY_DELTA < Math.abs(mPreviousDy - dy)) {
            mPreScrollChildRef = new WeakReference<>(child);
            mTotalDy += dy * FLING_FACTOR;
        }
        mPreviousDy = dy;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout child,
                                       View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        // Stop any previous fling animations that may be running
        onNestedFling(parent, child, target, 0, 0, false);
        return super.onStartNestedScroll(parent, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout abl, View target) {
        if(mTotalDy > 0 && mPreScrollChildRef != null && mPreScrollChildRef.get() != null) {
            // Programmatically trigger fling if all conditions are met
            onNestedFling(parent, mPreScrollChildRef.get(), target, 0, mTotalDy, false);
            mTotalDy = 0;
            mPreviousDy = 0;
            mPreScrollChildRef = null;
        }
        super.onStopNestedScroll(parent, abl, target);
    }
}
```

And apply it to the AppBar

```
AppBarLayout scrollView = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appbar);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)scrollView.getLayoutParams();
params.setBehavior(new NestedScrollViewBehavior());
```

CheeseSquare demo:
[Before](https://gfycat.com/InstructiveBrokenAfricanfisheagle) 
[After](https://gfycat.com/UnrealisticBriefAustraliancattledog)

Comment: It is indeed better than nothing, but not quite what an experienced Android user would expect. Thanks for linking the issue, I've starred it.

Comment: Had to remove the `enterAlways` layout_ScrollFlag for it to work, but working well now

Answer (score 3):

I tried Floofer's solution but it was still not good enough for me. So I came up with a better version of his Behavior. The AppBarLayout now expands and collapses smoothly when flinging.

**Note:** I used reflection to hack my way into this, so it may not work for perfectly with a version of Android Design library different from 25.0.0.

```
public class SmoothScrollBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {
    private static final String TAG = "SmoothScrollBehavior";
    //The higher this value is, the faster the user must scroll for the AppBarLayout to collapse by itself
    private static final int SCROLL_SENSIBILITY = 5;
    //The real fling velocity calculation seems complex, in this case it is simplified with a multiplier
    private static final int FLING_VELOCITY_MULTIPLIER = 60;

    private boolean alreadyFlung = false;
    private boolean request = false;
    private boolean expand = false;
    private int velocity = 0;
    private int nestedScrollViewId;

    public SmoothScrollBehavior(int nestedScrollViewId) {
        this.nestedScrollViewId = nestedScrollViewId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child,
                                  View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed);
        if(Math.abs(dy) >= SCROLL_SENSIBILITY) {
            request = true;
            expand = dy < 0;
            velocity = dy * FLING_VELOCITY_MULTIPLIER;
        } else {
            request = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout child,
                                       View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        request = false;
        return super.onStartNestedScroll(parent, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout appBarLayout, View target) {
        if(request) {
            NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) coordinatorLayout.findViewById(nestedScrollViewId);
            if (expand) {
                //No need to force expand if it is already ready expanding
                if (nestedScrollView.getScrollY() > 0) {
                    int finalY = getPredictedScrollY(nestedScrollView);
                    if (finalY <= 0) {
                        //since onNestedFling does not work to expand the AppBarLayout, we need to manually expand it
                        expandAppBarLayoutWithVelocity(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, velocity);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //onNestedFling will collapse the AppBarLayout with an animation time relative to the velocity
                onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, target, 0, velocity, true);

                if(!alreadyFlung) {
                    //TODO wait for AppBarLayout to be collapsed before scrolling for even smoother visual
                    nestedScrollView.fling(velocity);
                }
            }
        }
        alreadyFlung = false;
        super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, target);
    }

    private int getPredictedScrollY(NestedScrollView nestedScrollView) {
        int finalY = 0;
        try {
            //With reflection, we can get the ScrollerCompat from the NestedScrollView to predict where the scroll will end
            Field scrollerField = nestedScrollView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scrollerField.setAccessible(true);
            Object object = scrollerField.get(nestedScrollView);
            ScrollerCompat scrollerCompat = (ScrollerCompat) object;
            finalY = scrollerCompat.getFinalY();
        } catch (Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //If the reflection fails, it will return 0, which means the scroll has reached top
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get mScroller field from NestedScrollView through reflection. Will assume that the scroll reached the top.");
        }
        return finalY;
    }

    private void expandAppBarLayoutWithVelocity(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout appBarLayout, float velocity) {
        try {
            //With reflection, we can call the private method of Behavior that expands the AppBarLayout with specified velocity
            Method animateOffsetTo = getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("animateOffsetTo", CoordinatorLayout.class, AppBarLayout.class, int.class, float.class);
            animateOffsetTo.setAccessible(true);
            animateOffsetTo.invoke(this, coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, 0, velocity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //If the reflection fails, we fall back to the public method setExpanded that expands the AppBarLayout with a fixed velocity
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get animateOffsetTo method from AppBarLayout.Behavior through reflection. Falling back to setExpanded.");
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedPreFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        alreadyFlung = true;
        return super.onNestedPreFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY);
    }
}
```

To use it, set a new Behavior to your AppBarLayout.

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.setBehavior(new SmoothScrollBehavior(R.id.nested_scroll_view));
```

Comment: Your class demands an int in its' constructor, yet in the code you send nothing to the constructor

Comment: My bad, I added it.

Comment: This looks good, it makes the scrolling smooth, but I've one question, is it possible to let the NestedScrollView scroll into AppBarLayout once the AppBarLayout reach the top, and also, when I scroll down, AppBarLayout appears at last, when the NestedScrollView completely scrolled out, then AppBarLayout start to expand.

Comment: @ZijianWang Please explain me what you mean by "scroll into AppBarLayout" and I also don't understand your second question, can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32454407/2281718) solved this problem for me. Create a custom `AppBarLayout.Behavior` like this:

```
public final class FlingBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {
    private static final int TOP_CHILD_FLING_THRESHOLD = 3;
    private boolean isPositive;

    public FlingBehavior() {
    }

    public FlingBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNestedFling(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, float velocityX, float velocityY, boolean consumed) {
        if (velocityY > 0 && !isPositive || velocityY < 0 && isPositive) {
            velocityY = velocityY * -1;
        }
        if (target instanceof RecyclerView && velocityY < 0) {
            final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) target;
            final View firstChild = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
            final int childAdapterPosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(firstChild);
            consumed = childAdapterPosition > TOP_CHILD_FLING_THRESHOLD;
        }
        return super.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, child, target, velocityX, velocityY, consumed);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed);
        isPositive = dy > 0;
    }
}
```

and add it to the `AppBarLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.test.FlingBehavior">
```

Comment: Didn't work as the problem in the other question was the RecyclerView which isn't used here.

Answer (score 0):

Am just posting this here so that others do not miss it in Comments. The answer by [Jinang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40814431/7550472) works beautifully, but kudos to [AntPachon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40814431/7550472) for pointing out a far simpler method for the same. Instead of implementing an `OnClick` method on the `Child of the NestedScrollView` programatically, a better way is to set `clickable=true` in the xml for the child.

(Using the same example as [Jinang's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40814431/7550472))

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:clickable="true" >                  <!-- new -->

    <!-- Page Content -->

  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the code ：https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/core-ui/java/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.java#834

```
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (mIsBeingDragged) {
                final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
                velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000, mMaximumVelocity);
                int initialVelocity = (int) VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(velocityTracker,
                        mActivePointerId);
                if ((Math.abs(initialVelocity) > mMinimumVelocity)) {
                    flingWithNestedDispatch(-initialVelocity);
                } else if (mScroller.springBack(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), 0, 0, 0,
                        getScrollRange())) {
                    ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
                }
            }
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
            endDrag();
            break;
```

When i use a fling scroll on the NestedScrollView sometimes "mIsBeingDragged = false", So NestedScrollView dont dispatch fling event.

When i delete the `if (mIsBeingDragged)` statement.

```
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //if (mIsBeingDragged) {
            final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
            velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000, mMaximumVelocity);
            int initialVelocity = (int) VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(velocityTracker,
                    mActivePointerId);
            if ((Math.abs(initialVelocity) > mMinimumVelocity)) {
                flingWithNestedDispatch(-initialVelocity);
            } else if (mScroller.springBack(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), 0, 0, 0,
                    getScrollRange())) {
                ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
            }
        //}
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
        endDrag();
        break;
```

there will be no problem.**But I do not know what other serious problems will be caused**

Comment: Add more detail to make easy to understand answer, You wrote **When i remove the if...** from where you are talking to remove **if**?