# CollapsingToolbar don't scroll

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

in Android is used the followring Support-Library

> com.android.support:design:23.0.0

In my project i wan't to use the CollapsingToolbar with an image, but when i scroll in my app when the AppBar is visible, it's only scroll when I move the content and the content does not scroll alone. When the AppBar is invisible and the Toolbar is showing, it's work fine.

Show this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcojEVVJe7M

What can I do to make the scrolling works the same as with Google Play, Whatsapp, etc.??
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

     <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
         android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
         android:clipToPadding="true"
         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/header"
             app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
             app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />


         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
             app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
             app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
             app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


     </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_status"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="New Text" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum [...]"></TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: posting some code will be helpfull.....

Comment: Code from the Layout-File was added.

Comment: I think this is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31795483/559745

Comment: Yes, it's the same issue. Unfortunately, he also has no solution. Thanks anyway :)