# Single fling to uncollapse Android's CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have implemented a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with a parallax view.

When I scroll back up the RecyclerView in one continuous scroll it uncollapses the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

But when I issue a 'fling' the nested scroll view, it stops at the top of the nested scroll view. You have to fling again to uncollapse the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`,

The ScrollingActivity template in Android Studio 2.0 demonstrates this problem. And Chris Bain's [Cheesecake project](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare), in the detail view, demonstrates the same.

However, neither Google Play nor Spotify exhibit this problem in the 'view app' and 'playlist' views respectively. In a single fling, they will scroll to the top of the nested scroll view and uncollapse the toolbar.

Is this possible with the design library elements?

Edit: Ian has noted this reported [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179501). Please star it and post any work around you may have.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you set the `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` then it only takes a single fling. But in this case, I'm uncollapsing the toolbar far too early: I only want to uncollapse when I'm at the top of the nested scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Support Library 26.0.0-beta2 fixes this issue! See [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37053410#comment61).
It tested it and it is working fine!

Answer (score 3):

It is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179501), currently being worked on as mentioned in the [comments on this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/WojFEkDdFNe).

Comment: Thanks. I've starred the bug. Leaving the question open incase someone has a solution.