# Collapsing toolbar scrolls down on flick

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an issue with CollapsingToolbarLayout when I perform a very fast jerk.
The same thing happens with hidding appBar & tablayout.

I need toolbar to hide on scrolling and CollapsingToolbar to collapse. And it works fine when scroll's not so quick.

But when it's quick - it seems that appBar collapses and expandes right after that. But it hasn't to expand back.

---

Please take a look at videos.

[CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://youtu.be/e8Ni50NpEy4)

[appBar & tablayout](https://youtu.be/pxM8Xj0ujls)

---

It seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40814431/7825979) answer is what I need but it doesn't work.

---

xml of my CollapsingToolbarLayout :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      >
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        >
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivSectionCover"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
          />
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="130dp"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:alpha="0.5"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_gradient"
          />
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
          />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvEmptyList"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/books_empty_list"
      android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
      android:textSize="18sp"
      android:visibility="gone"
      />
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:clickable="true"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      >
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
      <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/rlContent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:clickable="true"
          >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvBooksSection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
      </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have also one recyclerview inside CollapsingToolbarLayout. when I scroll up, recyclerview perform action with jerk

Comment: @Nik please see my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the attribute Android: fitsSystemWindows="true" or change it to false. It looks like the layout is going behind the status bar. Fit system windows will allow the layout to go beyond the status bar and even the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, I haven't find a solution, but I reduced frequency of jerks by adding this:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =
    (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
if (behavior != null) {
  behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
    @Override public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
params.setBehavior(behavior);
```

also I edited layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  >
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentScrim="@color/colorLightGray"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    >
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/ivSectionCover"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@color/colorLightGray"
      app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
      />
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="170dp"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:alpha="0.5"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_gradient"
      />
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```