# RecyclerView with CollapsingToolbarLayout is scrolled badly when flinged

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I've found strange behavior in RecyclerView with CollapsingToolbarLayout.
When I scroll RecyclerView - it works perfectly. But when I try to fling it and stop that fling fast enough - I can see, that RecyclerView is scrolled "inside itself".

**Bad fling behavior:**

RecyclerView should not be scrollable before CollapsingToolbarLayout fully collapses, but it is (in normall scroll everything works perfectly, problem only appears when flinging).

[image]

My layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="kg.nongrate.arseniii.collapsingtoolbarlayouttest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="1. Hello World!\n\n\n2. Hello World!\n\n\n3. Hello World!"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0cc"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here are sources and two videos that show what I mean:
https://NonGrate@bitbucket.org/NonGrate/collapsingtoolbarlayout-recyclerview-bug.git

Comment: recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: Unfortunately, I need that RecyclerView to be scrollable, but only when CollapsingToolbarLayout is fully collapsed.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923889/flinging-with-recyclerview-appbarlayout)

Comment: @NonGrate did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @yausername no, we have changed the way we work with the layout instead. But I can see, there's some activity in the Kirill Simonov comment right above.