# NestedScrollView in AppBarLayout cut off at screen height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

I have a `AppBarLayout` with a `NestedScrollView`. I am trying to make it display correctly and have a fling effect when it is displayed.

**Originally** I had this layout:

```
 <FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                ...collapsing content
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            ...scrolling content
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

(with the `NestedScrollView` **outside** the `AppBarLayout`) It worked well but I could not fling the content when scrolling.

I used the advice in [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32454407/2946486), using the layout pattern in [the answer referenced by the accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174067/2946486) and moved the content **inside** the `AppBarLayout`. It now flings nicely, but the content contained in the `NestedScrollView` is cut off at the height of the screen. As you begin to scroll up you immediately see the end of the views despite the content being much longer.

My **current** Layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                >
            ... textviews etc
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried substituting `wrap_content` with `match_height` but this doesn't seem to be the problem.

I load all the content into `TextViews` via a webservice call and call `.RequestLayout();` on each `TextView` after I load the content.

**edit**

I have moved the `NestedScrollView` outside the `AppBarLayou` again. It flings when the `AppBarLayout` is collapsed, but not while it is open

Comment: Have you tried not nesting it all in a FrameLayout? Also have you tried calling `Invalidate()` on the scrollview?

Comment: @Cheesebaron thanks for your reply, I have now removed the outer Framelayout now. My class makes a RESTful webservice call from `OnCreateView` for the `TextView` content. I don't actually populate them (via `TextView.Text`) until an event listener is fired signaling that the data has been received. I am calling `.RequestLayout()` and subsequently `.Invalidate()` from the end of this listener method but with no change.

Comment: I have just loaded a large amount of lorem ipsum into a`TextView` in the `NestedScrollView` directly in the `XML` and it is cut off just the same so I think my problem must be there.

Comment: Hope you have found the solution. I am also struggling with the same issue. It would be great if you can a few minutes to share your answer here.