# How do I remove the bouncing effect on appbar?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, appbar, fling

Appbar used to have an issue when flinging. It was not scrolling smoothly.

Please refer to these:

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923889/flinging-with-recyclerview-appbarlayout
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177729&q=appbarlayout&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
- https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout

But it has been fixed in support library version 26.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
```

However, appbar is now bouncing back even if fling is not hard.

[image]

How do I remove this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is only happening when `AppBar` is scrolled/flung while the `NestedScrollView`(or `RecyclerView`) has not yet finish flinging.

**Solution:** Extend AppBar's default `Behavior` and block the call for AppBar.Behavior's `onNestedPreScroll()` and `onNestedScroll()` when `AppBar` is touched while NestedScroll hasn't stopped yet.

```
 @Override
public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed, int type) {
    if (type == TYPE_FLING) {
        isFlinging = true;
    }
    if (!shouldBlockNestedScroll) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type) {
    if (!shouldBlockNestedScroll) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type);
    }
}
```

then use it on the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    ...
    app:layout_behavior="com.mypackage.NoBounceBehavior"/>
```

**Reference** for full code of the custom behavior can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ampatron/9d56ea401094f67196f407f82f14551a

Comment: Just an extra note to any readers, remember to add the two class constructors as well in your NoBounce class or it will fail to load the new behavior.