# Could not inflate Behavior subclass

Tags: java, android, kotlin, behavior

I want to customize a behavior based on [How do I remove the bouncing effect on appbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152764)

But it always crashes during runtime:

```
2020-08-27 08:25:18.096 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tw.com.colatour.dev/tw.com.colatour.ui.mp.home.MpHomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Could not inflate Behavior subclass tw.com.colatour.dev.ui.app_home.ad.one.NoBounceBehavior
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2779)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6364)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Could not inflate Behavior subclass tw.com.colatour.dev.ui.app_home.ad.one.NoBounceBehavior
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass tw.com.colatour.dev.ui.app_home.ad.one.NoBounceBehavior
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:622)
```

How I use it in XML:

```xml
...
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior=".ui.app_home.ad.one.NoBounceBehavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"> 
...
```

Here is Java code solution but I don't know how to convert it to Kotlin code.

```java
public class NoBounceBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {
    
    public FooterBehavior() {
    }

    public FooterBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
```

Kotlin code:

```kotlin
//crash
class NoBounceBehavior(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
      AppBarLayout.Behavior(context, attrs) {

...
```

Another attempt which also crashes:

```kotlin
//crash
class NoBounceBehavior(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
      AppBarLayout.Behavior(context, attrs) {

    constructor() {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) {}
...
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti ok. I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the fully-qualified name of your custom behavior in your XML declaration. If the name specified in XML starts with a ".", [coordinator layout appends the package name at runtime](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/631f64e/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.java#392). If your app appends anything to the package name (ie ".beta" or ".dev") on build, the package name won't match the package path here. Use this instead:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="tw.com.colatour.ui.app_home.ad.one.NoBounceBehavior"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```