# Nested Scroll View height Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-nestedscrollview

I have implemented Google Maps with bottomsheet. However when I check the layout, the map is on the top of the screen, not occupying the whole width and height of the screen. I've tried many ways to fix this, but no luck.

[image]

[image]

Below is the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
           >
            <fragment  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.app.headcount.MapsActivity"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <include layout="@layout/test"
        android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"/>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Could you please have a look at this and let me know where exactly is the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: you want to show map on whole screen, but are not able to do the same. This is your question?

Comment: @Vyshaks, you are using    android:layout_weight="1" parameter along with android:layout_height="match_parent". Try to setpup height to 0dp, so android could calculate weight properly

Comment: Why is the map fragment inside a scroll view ?

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806119/nestedscrollview-and-coordinatorlayout-issue-on-scrolling

Answer (score 6):

try to use  android:fillViewport="true"